# Factory pattern inside object literal to accomplish iterability and reflection

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to construct instances from a factory and have them look like instances created by `new Instance()` -- meaning the constructors, and prototypes, are indistinguishable from an instance created by `new`.

The factory is going to reside in an object literal so its call would look like

```
var instance=App.factory.Instance.create(arg1,...);
```

Note that the 'classname' "Instance" is not passed into a generic creator.

The other requirement is that the members of this `Instance` reside in the object literal, and if no constructor is provided, then a default (no-op) is used.

The members residing in the literal are for purposes of iteration and reflection, this is why any approach which does things out in white space is not going to work.

```
/* jshint laxcomma: true */
window.App={
      _name:'App'// convention
      ,factory:{
        _name:'factory'
        // begin specifying classes
        ,Instance:{ // this is a mini-factory of type 'Instance',
                    // a 'create' method is dynamically injected when 'factory' is initialized
          _name:'Instance'
          ,ctor:function Instance(a,b){ // OPTIONAL specified constructor, want to ditch fn name here if possible
          }
          ,template:{ // Instance spec container. Is like 'Instance.prototype'
            //_name:'template' // convention, but will not be a member of 'instance'
            valueMember:'something' // this will exist on finished 'prototype'
            ,funcMember:function(){  // this will exist on finished 'prototype'
            }
          }
          ,_static:{ // these will be placed on 'Instance' (constructor)
            _name:'_static' // convention, but not placed
            ,valueMember:'something' // this will exist on 'Instance' (constructor)
            ,funcMember:function(){  // this will exist on 'Instance' (constructor)
            }
          }
          //,create:function(){} is injected during init of factory
        }// - Instance
        // more classes like Instance here...
      }
    };
App.factory.Instance.create=function(){ // this must be generic/agnostic to 'Instance'
      var that=this; // this is 'Instance:'
      function init(){
        if (that.ctor===undefined) { // user did not provide constructor
          //that.ctor=new Function(''); // BAD WAY
          // make a generic constructor with correct name
          that.ctor=eval('(function '+that._name+'(){})');
        }
        // preserve constructor for reuse
        that._ctor=that.ctor;        
        delete that.ctor;
        var i;
        if (typeof that._static==='object') { // put statics on constructor
          for (i in that._static) {
            if (i!=='_name') {                // ignore convention
              that._ctor[i]=that._static[i];
            }
          }
        }
        // doing it whole here, should be a cleaned-of-convention duplicate object
        that._ctor.prototype=that.template;
        that._ctor.name=that._name;
        // this line confuses me, something should be done, do I need it?
        //that._ctor.prototype.constructor=that._ctor; // produces 'constructor' in instance        
      }
      // look in cache
      if (that._ctor===undefined) {
        init();
      }
      // NOW THE HARD PART - HOW TO INVOKE
      var rv;
      var fn=that._ctor;
      //rv=construct(fn,arguments);
      //rv= new fn();
      rv=new that._ctor();
      // HERE
      // fn.prototype.constructor=fn;
      // My problem at this point is getting instance.constructor to
      // not be 'Object' but if I include the line above
      // it shows 'constructor' as iterable
      // however THIS LINE WORKS, but why? BUT Why do I have to do it here, after construction?
      rv.constructor.prototype.constructor=that._ctor;
      // NO that._ctor.prototype.constructor=that._ctor; puts 'constructor' on instance
      return rv;
      }; //-create
function Classic(a,b){

}
Classic.prototype.member="member";
var classic=new Classic();

var instance=App.factory.Instance.create();
console.log('classic',classic);
console.log('instance',instance);
console.log('classic.constructor',classic.constructor);
console.log('instance.constructor',instance.constructor);
console.log('instance.constructor.name',instance.constructor.name);
console.log('classic.constructor.name',classic.constructor.name);
```

I have it halfway working, but I suffer from confusion and look for improvement in the basic approach. Also, am I missing any wiring that would make `instance` distinguishable from a classically constructed object?

Broadening this idea, it seems there should be a library that will take such templating and produce factories where classes are constructed via `Object.defineProperty` thereby giving more control - i.e. `_readonly` etc. A language inside a language.

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jepizosobo/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: if you do not find any library doing this take it as a sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
,ctor:function Instance(a,b){ // OPTIONAL specified constructor, want to ditch fn name here if possible
```

The name of the class can be removed here if you later create a function with `name` equal to `_name` that just calls `ctor` like this `ctor.call(this);`

```
App.factory.Instance.create=function(){ // this must be generic/agnostic to 'Instance'
```

It looks like, in order to be agnostic to `Instance` you added the `_name` convention. You could also create a function that takes your `App` object and add the `_name` field recursively. Another possibility is to pass `factory` instead of `Instance` to the function that is going to add the `create` methods.

```
that._ctor.name=that._name;
```

This code does nothing, because the name of a function is a read-only property. It is also not needed since the code `eval('(function '+that._name+'(){})')` already created the function with the name you wanted.

```
fn.prototype.constructor=fn
```

When you declare a function it automatically gets a prototype with the constructor field set to that function. You had to set the constructor field of the prototype with `rv.constructor.prototype.constructor=that._ctor;` because you replaced the prototype with template. You could have done this before or after `rv=new that._ctor();`.

```
classic instanceof Classic
instance instanceof App.factory.Instance
```

And this is what is going to make objects created by your factory distinguishable from objects created normally. In order for the `instanceof` operator to work `App.factory.Instance` needs to be the constructor function.

Here is the code that I came up with that follows your requirements.

```js
App = {
    factory: {
        Instance: {
            template: {
                c: 3,
                d: 4
            },
            _static: {
                e: 5,
                f: 6
            },
            constructor: function (a, b) {
                this.a = a;
                this.b = b;
            }
        }
    }
};

function init(factory) {
    for (var name in factory) {
        var constructor = eval('(function ' + name + '(){})');
        constructor.prototype = factory[name].template;
        Object.defineProperty(constructor.prototype, 'constructor', {
            value: constructor,
            enumerable: false
        });
        for (var property in factory[name]._static) {
            constructor[property] = factory[name]._static[property];
        }
        var previous = factory[name].constructor;
        var create = function () {
            var instance = new constructor();
            if (previous) {
                previous.apply(instance, arguments);
            }
            return instance;
        }
        factory[name] = constructor;
        factory[name].create = create;
    }
}

init(App.factory);

function Classic(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
};
Classic.prototype.c = 3;
Classic.prototype.d = 4;
Classic.e = 5;
Classic.f = 6;

var classic = new Classic(1, 2);
var instance = App.factory.Instance.create(1, 2);

console.log('classic', classic);
console.log('instance', instance);
console.log('classic.constructor', classic.constructor);
console.log('instance.constructor', instance.constructor);
console.log('instance.constructor.name', instance.constructor.name);
console.log('classic.constructor.name', classic.constructor.name);
console.log('classic instanceof Classic', classic instanceof Classic);
console.log('instance instanceof App.factory.Instance', instance instanceof App.factory.Instance);

console.log('classic.a', classic.a);
console.log('classic.b', classic.b);
console.log('classic.c', classic.c);
console.log('classic.d', classic.d);
console.log('Classic.e', Classic.e);
console.log('Classic.f', Classic.f);

console.log('instance.a', instance.a);
console.log('instance.b', instance.b);
console.log('instance.c', instance.c);
console.log('instance.d', instance.d);
console.log('App.factory.Instance.e', App.factory.Instance.e);
console.log('App.factory.Instance.f', App.factory.Instance.f);
```